# System services not available to activities before onCreate() on trying to implement getSystemService()

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to implement a AlertDialog which should open up on pressing the the 'activate' button, but  on pressing the button, the app crashes.

Here's my code.

MainActivity-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button activateButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    activateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.activate);
    activateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Speed s = new Speed();
        }
    });

}
```

And here's another class called Speed which contains the code for AlertDialog

```
public class Speed extends Activity {
    LocationManager mManager;
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
    AlertDialog.Builder box = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Speed(){
        Status();
    }

    private void Status(){

        if(!mManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            DialogBox();
        }
    }

    protected void DialogBox(){
        AlertDialog.Builder box = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        box.setTitle("The GPS needs to be enabled. Would you like to enable the GPS?").setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alert = box.create();
        alert.show();

    }

}
```

Also, here's the log with error in the context

```
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3989)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at com.scimet.admin.driveon.Speed.<init>(Speed.java:12)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at com.scimet.admin.driveon.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:25)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-01 21:27:00.439: E/AndroidRuntime(5503):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my first Android project. and on searching for multiple hours to try and resolve this issue, I've ended up with no solution. Please point out the mistake.

Thank you!

Comment: you need to do all that in your onCreate

Comment: Okay. But why? I'm sorry, I don't know how to structure a code. Also, I'll be adding some GPS functionality to the Speed class.

Comment: because that is when its available

Comment: It doesn't look like Speed should be an Activity. Should it not be a standard class into which you can pass the MainActivity? Activities should not be instantiated with 'new' but instead launched via the intent system.

Comment: Thanks, but could you be more specific? What is available when? Am I complicating my design?

Comment: @daentech, right, thanks! I'll look into that. Re-arranging my code now.

Comment: I tried instantiating AlertDialog in my MainActivity, but it gives me a nullpointerexception. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this code inside onCreate method, because it will run when the activity is created.

For example

in your class remove constructor.

Then on onCreate method of the activity you do:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  LocationManager manager; 
  AlertDialog.Builder box;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    box = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
    Status();
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `super` call first. You will have the same result as the OP without it.

Answer (score 1):

An activity should be used for presenting a different user flow and shouldn't be instantiated using 'new'.

If you replace the  Speed instantiation line in MainActivity with this:

```
Speed s = new Speed(MainActivity.this);
```

and instead treat Speed as a standard class and pass in the MainActivity as a Context object.

```
public class Speed{
    LocationManager mManager;
    final LocationManager manager;
    AlertDialog.Builder box;

    final Context context;


    Speed(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        mManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
        Status();
    }

    private void Status(){

        if(!mManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            DialogBox();
        }
    }
    protected void DialogBox(){
        AlertDialog.Builder box = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
        box.setTitle("The GPS needs to be enabled. Would you like to enable the GPS?").setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alert = box.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

You will only need to do this if you want to keep the separation between the Speed handling stuff and the activity itself.